# how many distinct number group possibilities exist in a powerball drawing if you exclude the powerball

Tags: arithmetic

in a powerball lottery draw you choose 5 numbers out of 59 with no repeating numbers how many distinct number groupings does this amount to

is there an equation that can be used to calculate this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Combinatorial_interpretation

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{59!}{59!\cdot(59-5)!}.$

Comment: Often pronounced "59 choose 5"